# Need a word for flipping a switch/button on then off right after

Tags: word-request

I need a word for interacting with a machine to flip/switch a button ON then OFF right after.

The word restart doesn't really work. I've found the words toggle, switching, and flipping.

Are there any others?

Comment: 'Power cycle' is a phrase sometimes used with turning a machine/computer on/off. I don't think any of these phrases inherently convey 'immediately', so you may have to use 'flip the switch on and then off again straight after' or similar.

Comment: There's always scope for confusion with ***soft / hard reset*** (where the "hard" version normally implies discarding all user data, aka ***factory** reset*), but you might consider [***soft restart***](https://lightningdetroit.com/restart-your-computer/) - *A soft restart is when you restart your computer using its software (and not the physical power button).* As opposed to ***hard restart*** - *A hard restart is when you restart your computer using the physical power button ... To perform a hard restart, simply press and hold the power button until the computer shuts down.*

Answer (score 2):

In UK English it is sometimes said that you **throw** a switch.

You could also say that you **flip** the switch on then off.

The words **jiggle** or **joggle** have also been used to describe rapid on/off switching.

Comment: I’m sure ‘jiggle’ and ‘joggle’ could be used, but I am not sure everyone would understand you due to it depending on where you are in the world.

Comment: @Buzzyy Good point, but I did start my answer with *In UK English*

Comment: 'Flip' in connection with switches is a mainly US thing. In the UK, we tend to press or throw them.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset** could be a possible answer, but as far as I see there is an english word for turning something of and on again.

Toggle, switching and flipping also only mean to turn it on/off, rather than to do both.